# Polymer paper-slider behaves strangely when setting "min" by data binding

Tags: html, polymer, bower, polymer-1.0

I am using `Polymer`'s `paper-slider` in my custom element. I am passing a `min` property in my custom element and assigning it to the `min` value of the slider. However the slider is behaving strangely, where it does not slide until the cursor goes to either extreme and the value keeps changing in a very high range.

Here is the code:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-slider/paper-slider.html">

<dom-module id="slider-two">
    <template>
        <br>
        <br>
        <paper-slider pin min=[[min]]></paper-slider>

    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'slider-two',
            properties: {
                min: {
                    type: String
                }
            }
        });
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

Usage:

```
<slider-two min='5'></slider-two>
```

What is the error in the code which causes this strange behaviour. Replacing `min=[[min]]` in the code by `max=[[min]]` gives the expected correct result, and the strange behaviour is caused by `min` only. I have tried changing the name to something other than `min` too.

I installed it using `bower i --save paper-slider` and I am using `Polymer 1.0.0` (for it to be compatible with a certain `leaflet-map`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the issue is that you are declaring the `min` property as a `String` but according to the documentation it should be a number: [paper-slider docs](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-slider/elements/paper-slider#property-min).

> min: number = 0 notify
> Inherited from Polymer.IronRangeBehavior
>
> The number that indicates the minimum value of the range.

Try declaring `min` as `Number`:

```
Polymer({
    is: 'slider-two',
    properties: {
        min: {
            type: Number
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: But then why does it work with other properties lilke `max`, `value` and `step` (which are other properties we can set on `paper-slider`?

Comment: It works with `Number`. Though I still do not understand how `String` worked for `max` and the others.

Comment: `iron-slider` uses `iron-range-behavior` for managing its numeric value. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-range-behavior/blob/dcc636b9fd86c8eeeb1cbd4cade2f6d34ebcb168/iron-range-behavior.html#L79) line where the step is calculated: the `min` property is added to the previous value. If `min` is a `String` the result of this add operation is a string concatenation instead of a numeric addition. Try to `console.log()` `immediateValue` at line ~ 629 of `paper-slider` and you'll see a sequence of strings all ending with `min`'s digits instead of the correct numbers.

Comment: true that. Also `this.max` escaped from such errors as it never occurs along with `+` as [here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-range-behavior/blob/dcc636b9fd86c8eeeb1cbd4cade2f6d34ebcb168/iron-range-behavior.html#L54).